# Getting a Java.lang.NullPointerException while creating Hibernate Mapping File(hbm.xml)

Tags: xml, hibernate, jboss, hbm

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while creating hibernate mapping file(hbm.xml). I am using Eclipse IDE 2020-06 and JBoss Tools 4.16.0 final.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wipro</groupId>
  <artifactId>Introduction_to_Hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="sessionfactory1">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">tiger</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">scott</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <mapping class="com.wipro.bean.Emp"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Emp.java**

```
package com.wipro.bean;

import java.util.Date;

public class Emp {
    private int empno;
    private String ename;
    private String job;
    private int mgr;
    private Date hiredate;
    private float sal;
    private float comm;
    private int deptno;
    public Emp() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Emp(int empno, String ename, String job, int mgr, Date hiredate, float sal, float comm, int deptno) {
        super();
        this.empno = empno;
        this.ename = ename;
        this.job = job;
        this.mgr = mgr;
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
        this.sal = sal;
        this.comm = comm;
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }
    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }
    public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }
    public String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }
    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }
    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }
    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }
    public int getMgr() {
        return mgr;
    }
    public void setMgr(int mgr) {
        this.mgr = mgr;
    }
    public Date getHiredate() {
        return hiredate;
    }
    public void setHiredate(Date hiredate) {
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
    }
    public float getSal() {
        return sal;
    }
    public void setSal(float sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }
    public float getComm() {
        return comm;
    }
    public void setComm(float comm) {
        this.comm = comm;
    }
    public int getDeptno() {
        return deptno;
    }
    public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emp [empno=" + empno + ", ename=" + ename + ", job=" + job + ", mgr=" + mgr + ", hiredate=" + hiredate
                + ", sal=" + sal + ", comm=" + comm + ", deptno=" + deptno + "]";
    }
}
```

**Error Logs**

**Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.16.0.I20200604-0540
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jface
Error
Mon Aug 31 00:53:20 IST 2020
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.getService(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.access$1(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard$HibernateMappingExporterWrapper.<init>(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.getPlaces2Gen(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.handlePageChanging(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$6.run(WizardDialog.java:1565)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.firePageChanging(WizardDialog.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.doPageChanging(WizardDialog.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

**Unhandled event loop exception**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.16.0.I20200604-0540
java.version=11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Mon Aug 31 01:00:37 IST 2020
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.codetogether.ui.actions.EclipseOfferOnSelection.scrollingChanged(EclipseOfferOnSelection.java:419)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.codetogether.ui.actions.EclipseOfferOnSelection$ScrollingListener.widgetSelected(EclipseOfferOnSelection.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendSelectionEvent(Widget.java:1078)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ScrollBar.wmScrollChild(ScrollBar.java:1001)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.wmScroll(Scrollable.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.WM_VSCROLL(Scrollable.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4829)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4923)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.wmScrollWheel(Scrollable.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.WM_MOUSEWHEEL(Scrollable.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4788)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4923)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3628)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

**Screenshot**

[Screenshot of the NullPointerException occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRziN.jpg)